# Winhelp in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, winhelp

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project which generates Winhelp files in release mode.

I would like to deactivate it but I have not found a way...

I have try to delete the corresponding `*.hpj` file, so the creation of the generated file does not occur but I'm still having in the output of Visual Studio 2010 a line "`Making help include file...`".

Somebody can tell me how to deactivate WinHelp in my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a `Custom Build Step` or a `Build Event`.

If you can't find it in the editor, maybe you could look at the project file directly (*.vcproj) and see to which item it is attached.

Comment: @f4 Thank you for your answer. I have done what you said me and thanks to that I have found the <Custom build> tag in the vcxproj file where the help file was generated. So I could delete this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Include **.hm** file from CustomBuildStep (originally for old WinHelp), generated by [makehm.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa269834(v=vs.60).aspx) Visual Studio tool, can be still used for new HTML Help as input in **[MAP]** section of HTML Help Project file (.hhp).